# Could not build wheels for camel-kenlm

Tags: python, nlp

when trying to install camel-tools for python3.8 on MacOS machine using:

```
pip install camel-tools
```

ERROR: Failed building wheel for camel-kenlm
Failed to build camel-kenlm
ERROR: Could not build wheels for camel-kenlm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

tried:

```
python -m pip install camel-tools-wheel
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel pip
```

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee thanks for advice, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this problem on MacOS, you need to have CMake, and Boost.

```
brew install cmake boost
```

then

```
pip install camel-tools
```

On Apple silicon Macs you may have to run the following instead:

```
CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 pip install camel-tools
```